# simple xmlstarlet example to copy files

Tags: terminal, command-prompt, xmlstarlet

Windows Command Prompt. I want to do the following in a ONE-LINER COMMAND.
i want to set a variable with a simple xml structure:

```
<pathlist>
<path>C:\file.txt</path>
<path>C:\file2.txt</path>
</pathlist>
```

like this:

```
SET "_myvar=^<pathlist^>^<path^>C:\file.txt^</path^> ^<path^>C:\file2.txt^</path^>^</pathlist^>"
```

then i want to echo this and pipe it to xmlstarlet:

```
echo !_myvar!|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "//path"
```

then the result should be put into another var sourcefiles, with a for loop?

```
 for /f %i in ('call echo %^_myVar%^|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "/*" ') do set sourcefiles=%i
```

and finally pscp sourcefile to a remote Unix

```
pscp -l user-pw password %sourcefiles% openstack@remoteIP:/opt/testfolder
```

i cannot use temporary files for this taks, i tried this:

```
SET "_myVar=^<pathlist^>^<path^>C:\file1.txt^</path^> ^<path^>C:\file2.txt^</path^>^</pat
hlist^>"& for /f %i in ('cmd /v:on /c echo !_myVar!|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "/*" ') do set sourcefiles=%i &&cmd /v:on /
c pscp -l user -pw password %sourcefiles% openstack@remoteIp:/opt/testfolder
```

and get this error:

```
| was unexpected at this time.
```

the problem is when i want to echo the var content to xmlstarlet, i think. Anybody know how to solve this?

**Edit**
using call echo instead of cmd /v:on in a slighty simplified command i get this error:

```
SET "_myVar=^<pathlist^>^<path^>C:\file1.txt^</path^> ^<path^>C:\file2.txt^</path^>^</pat
    hlist^>"& 'call echo ^^%^_myVar!%^^|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "/*"
```

error:

```
-:1.1: Document is empty

^
-:1.1: Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET "_myVar=^<pathlist^>^<path^>C:\file1.txt^</path^> ^<path^>C:\file2.txt^</path^>^</pathlist^>"& for /f %i in ('cmd /v:on /c echo !_myVar!^|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "/*" ') do set sourcefiles=%i &&cmd /v:on /c pscp -l user -pw password %sourcefiles% openstack@remoteIp:/opt/testfolder
```

should fix your `| was unexpected at this time.` error. The only change is to escape the pipe with `^`, which tells `cmd` that the pipe is part of the command, not an instruction to `cmd`.

---

My focus was on the error-report about the pipe.

What I found was that `echo` doesn't line `<` as the first character of the string being `echo`ed - so I toyed around with it a while.

And then I cut the grass and cleaned up the yard a bit.

And then I thought - well, how about `sed`? I use GNUSED, and since you're outputting to a *Nix system, the world of SED shouldn't be too fearsome.

How about - as a batch file,

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "uname=%~1"&shift
SET "pass=%~1"&shift
SET "sourcefiles="
SET "_myVar=*pathlist?"
:dirloop
IF "%~1" neq "" SET "_myvar=%_myvar% *path?%~1*/path?"&shift&GOTO dirloop
SET "_myvar=%_myvar%*/pathlist?"
for /f %%i in ('echo %_myvar%^|sed s/\x2a/\x3c/g^;s/\x3f/\x3e/g^|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "/*" ') do ECHO %%i&set "sourcefiles=!sourcefiles! %%i"
ECHO pscp -l %uname% -pw %pass% %sourcefiles% openstack@remoteIp:/opt/testfolder
```

Which you could execute as a single line

*thisbatch* user password path1 path2 path3...

(yeah - the `pscp` is just being echoed for verification...)

or, for an all-in-one-line version, which I'll spread over several for clarity's sake (and because I wrote it in a "DOS" session):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "_myvar=*pathlist?*path?C:\file.txt*/path? *path?C:\file2.txt*/path?*/pathlist?"
SET "sourcefiles="
for /f %%i in ('echo %_myvar%^|sed s/\x2a/\x3c/g^;s/\x3f/\x3e/g^|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "/*" ') do set "sourcefiles=!sourcefiles! %%i"
ECHO pscp -l user -pw password !sourcefiles! openstack@remoteIp:/opt/testfolder
```

SInce `*` and `?` can't be used as legitimate filename characters, including them in the string `set` into the environment, then using `echo` to send *? to `sed` which converts them to `<>` for input to `xmlstarlet` - now that might work (but I don't have `xmlstarlet` for testing - I conclude it simply outputs a list of some variety...)

Note the `^` to escape the `;` in the `sed` command!

---

Here's the all-in-one-line version that may work

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&SET "_myvar=*pathlist?*path?C:\file.txt*/path? *path?C:\file2.txt*/path?*/pathlist?"&SET "sourcefiles="&(for /f %%i in ('echo %_myvar%^|sed s/\x2a/\x3c/g^;s/\x3f/\x3e/g^|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "/*" ') do set "sourcefiles=!sourcefiles! %%i")&pscp -l user -pw password !sourcefiles! openstack@remoteIp:/opt/testfolder
```

but I've no way of testing this in your environment.

---

Here's the line I used:

```dos
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&SET "_myvar=*pathlist?*path?C:\file.txt*/path? *path?C:\file2.txt*/path?*/pathlist?"&SET "sourcefiles="&(for /f %%i in ('echo %_myvar%^|sed s/\x2a/\x3c/g^;s/\x3f/\x3e/g^|xmlstarlet sel -t  -v  "/*" ') do set "sourcefiles=!sourcefiles! %%i")&pscp -l user -pw password !sourcefiles! openstack@remoteIp:/opt/testfolder
```

I used a batch file called **xmlstarlet.bat**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO phial1.txt
ECHO phial2.txt
ECHO phial3.txt
ECHO phial4.txt
ECHO phial5.txt
```

which should simply produce 5 lines of output when run

I used a batch file called **pscp.bat**

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
ECHO running PSCP
ECHO %*
PAUSE
```

And the result was:

```
running PSCP
-l user -pw password  phial1.txt phial2.txt phial3.txt phial4.txt phial5.txt openstack@remoteIp:/opt/testfolder
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: thanks!, how would the code work with CALL ECHO instead of CMD /V:ON? could not get it to work

Comment: for the allinoneline version, i would not need the SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION, right? or would i have to use CALL ECHO in that case?

Comment: The SETLOCAL... would mean you don't need to use `cmd/v` but would likely be unnecessary if your application executes the one-liner as `cmd /v.....`

Comment: i used the oneliner and i got `C:\Users\user1>set "sourcefiles=!sourcefiles! C:\file.txt"
-l user -pw password !sourcefiles! openstack@remoteIp:/opt/testfolder
` so the for loop does not fet the file2.txt and the last command does not get the value